# svgPanZoom: only pan using middle mouse button

Tags: javascript, svgpanzoom

Is there an easy way to only pan when the middle mouse button is pressed? The default behavior is to pan whatever mouse button is pressed (or any touches).

The `beforepan` looked promising but you only get the old and new position without knowing what triggered the panning.

I can probably get it to work using the [`customEventsHandler`](https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom/blob/master/demo/custom-event-handlers.html) but it seems like a lot of extra work for a couple of simple checks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before calling the `svgPanZoom` on the element, you could bind a mousedown event and call [`stopImmediatePropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation).

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/6p84yfff/1/)

```js
document.getElementById('svg-id').onmousedown = function (e) {
  if (e.button !== 1) e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}

svgPanZoom('#svg-id', {
  zoomEnabled: true,
  controlIconsEnabled: true,
  fit: true,
  center: true,
  minZoom: 0.1
});
```

```css
#container{
  width: 300px; height: 300px; border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ariutta.github.io/svg-pan-zoom/dist/svg-pan-zoom.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <svg id="svg-id" height="300px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g>
      <g stroke="#000" fill="#FFF">
        <rect x="10" y="10" width="120" height="120" fill="red"/>
        <path d="M 10 10  L 130 130 Z"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no easy way of changing the events that handle the panning. You basically have 2 solutions:

- Change the source code and compile your own version. This should be straightforward, but has the downside that whenever the library updates - you'll have to recompile your version if you want the latest version. On the other hand version 3 is very stable, and only minor things changed during last two years.
- use `customEventsHandler`. Yes, it is not trivial, but you get the benefit of not changing the core. It should be  quite simple as you can use the `panBy` and pass only the delta between last mouse position and current mouse position (without needing to worry about the SVG current scale/zoom).